# Machine Learning Algorithm with Sigmoid function has it's parameters initialized to zero

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I have a doubt, it may sound silly, but I need to understand this deeply.

For a machine learning algo. using numpy and has sigmoid fn. `(s = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))`

When we are using this we initialize the parameters with zeros...

```
w = np.zeros((dim,1))
b = 0
```

So when we are executing `z = np.dot(w.T, X) + b` As this being a dot product, z must always be zero. I know this is not right. But looking at the prob as `w` is an array of zero and when it's multiplied with `x` the result will be zero. This is my doubt. Can someone explain this to me. I appreciate your efforts. Thanks.

Comment: What is your doubt? It's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `z` evaluates to zero, `sigmoid(z)`, and it's derivative, are non-zero (`0.5`, `0.25` respectively) at `z=0`.

When you perform the back-propagation of your network, the non-zero values of these quantities permits a non-zero contribution to your weights.

Answer (score 1):

"For a machine learning algorithm using numpy and has a sigmoid function.." Some aspects of your question are not clear.

But to answer your question about z being 0 always - this will not happen as Graeme has clearly explained that during back-propagation the derivative of the cost function will contribute a non-zero value resulting in the weights changing appropriately. But you have not specified which algorithm you're using. By convention, we initialize the parameters to random, dissimilar values but not zero. Initializing to zero will ensure your algorithm doesn't learn anything in case you're using a Neural Network. But it's okay if you're using Logistic regression.

A nice explanation is given by Prof Ng. at [Link](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/ND5G5/random-initialization). Hope this helps clarify things.